# Failed to stop the timer for audio when clicked on Pause button using Recorder.js

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, audio-recording

I have successfully added a timer to the audio recorder but failed to stop when clicked on the pause button.

I am using the example mentioned below.

- Blog Post - https://blog.addpipe.com/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/
- Original Source code - https://github.com/addpipe/simple-recorderjs-demo
- Working Example Link - https://addpipe.com/simple-recorderjs-demo/

I have modified the HTML and JS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="audio-input-area">

    <div id="controls">
        <button id="recordButton">Record</button>
        <button id="pauseButton" disabled>Pause</button>
        <button id="stopButton" disabled>Stop</button>
    </div>
    

    <!--- Added .status-text paragraph for timer --->

    <p id="status-text"></p> 
   
    <div id="recordingsList"></div>
    
</div>
```

**JS**

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {

    ................Existing code..................
    .................Existing code.....................
    

    // Added the code below for the timer

    intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
        
        floatValue = Math.floor( audioContext.getOutputTimestamp(stream).contextTime )
        statusText.innerText = secondsToHms(floatValue);

        // console.log(secondsToHms(floatValue));
        // console.log(audioContext.currentTime);
        /// call your function here
        // console.log(audioContext.getOutputTimestamp(stream))
        // console.log(floatValue);
        
    }, 1000);
    
    
    ..............Existing code....................
    ................Existing code......................
}
```

Comment: The buttons don't seem to do anything. Are you adding onclick functions to them in js? If so, please show those functions (and how you add onclick to them) so that we can see what is wrong with them.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson Thanks for your reply. You can download the source code from the GitHub link mentioned above

Comment: @EmilKarlsson I have updated my links